# How to fix TypeError: this.props.changeCategory is not a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hooks

I'm working in code Sandbox IDE and I have a problem with component ProductList and I tried to add functions in App.js.

I'm passing function as props in component ProductList but I am getting an error showing TypeError:this.props.changeCategory is not a function. I have written code as" `onClick={() => this.props.changeCategory(category)}`" 
I described this function at App.js as

```
changeCategory = category => {
    this.setState({ currentCategory: category.categoryName });
  };
```

My error message :

```
    TypeError
_this2.props.changeCategory is not a function
onClick
/src/components/ProductList.js:21:40
  18 | <ListGroup>
  19 |   {this.state.categories.map(category => (
  20 |     <ListGroupItem
> 21 |       onClick={() => this.props.changeCategory(category)}
     |                                ^
  22 |       key={category.categoryId}
  23 |     >
  24 |       {" "}
```

ProductList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from "reactstrap";

import "../styles.css";
class ProductList extends Component {
  state = {
    categories: [
      { categoryId: 1, categoryName: "Beverages" },
      { categoryId: 2, categoryName: "Sunny Side UP" },
      { categoryId: 3, categoryName: "Whats sup" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3> {this.props.uc} </h3>
        <ListGroup>
          {this.state.categories.map(category => (
            <ListGroupItem
              onClick={() => this.props.changeCategory(category)}
              key={category.categoryId}
            >
              {" "}
              {category.categoryName}{" "}
            </ListGroupItem>
          ))}
        </ListGroup>
        <form className="f">{this.props.currentCategory}</form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ProductList;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Navi from "./components/Navi";
import Cl from "./components/CategoryList";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import Pl from "./components/ProductList";

class App extends Component {
  state = { currentCategory: " " };

  changeCategory = category => {
    this.setState({ currentCategory: category.categoryName });
  };
  render() {
    let titleCategory = "List One";
    let CategoryInfo = { uc: "List Two" };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Navi />
          </Row>

          <Row>
            <Col xs="4">
              <Pl
                uc={titleCategory}
                changeCategory={this.state.changeCategory}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col xs="8">
              <Cl info={CategoryInfo} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Can anyone suggest me where am I doing wrong? Thanks all.

Comment: changeCategory={this.changeCategory} its a function not a state value.

Comment: oh youre right ,thanks a lot

Comment: So... Is it solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the function changeCategory from App.js to ProductList. To pass the function as props, you should write as below in your App.js file but you are passing the state value.

```
<pl changeCategory ={this.changeCategory} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You were passing wrong data to changeCategory props in App.js for product list component. you have to give function reference to this props.

```
 <Pl uc={titleCategory} changeCategory={this.changeCategory} />
```